# Vue, how do I pass data to component in render method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This is the main vue component. I want to make an ajax request and pass the data using the render method to my app component, which is a standalone component in a different file. How do I pass this data and how can I retrieve it in my app component. I am learning Vue, I know how to do this with `<template></template>` but would like to know if it is possible to do it this way.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        data: {}
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get("http://stag.cyberserge.com:4000/autos").then(res => this.data = res.data)
    },
    render: h => h(App, this.data)
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass it as a property.

```
render(h){
  return h(App, {props: {appData: this.data}})
},
```

See the documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth).

In your App component, add appData (or whatever you want to call it) as a property.

```
export default {
    props: ["appData"],
    ...
}
```

Here is an example of this [working](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/WOQmGX?editors=1010).

Comment: This is not working for me. I created an arrow func as the second arg to render, to check if the data is there, seems like this is bound to the arrow func and the data is undefined.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi The second argument cannot be a function, then you are passing a function to `createElement`, which explicitly only accepts an object. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Not sure why the data is undefined then. In my App component I do this `props: ["appData"],

    data(){
        return { data: this.appData }
    },`

Comment: In the render method if I set appData to an int/str it works but if I use this.data it doesn't work even when I remove the ajax call in mounted and initialize this.data to some random string. I think `this` might be an issue here.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi sorry I wrote this last night on my phone and I missed the implication of you using an arrow function for your render method. The problem with that will be `this` points to the wrong thing, I updated my example using a proper function.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi There is an additional problem with the code that you wrote in your comment; the initialization of your data property in `App` only happens once. If you want it to work like that, you will need to use a watcher to watch changes to the property and set data appropriately.

Comment: Here is an example of it working using your approach to initialization. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GEpeEr?editors=1010

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146183/discussion-between-yasin-yaqoobi-and-bert-evans).